# JButton "stay pressed" after click in Java Applet

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jbutton

I have a JButton in my Java Applet. After pressing it, ActionListener have to make huge amount of actions. So, because of it, when user clicks the button, it "stay pressed" for a while (sometimes even 5 minuts) instead of disable itself immidiately (it disable itself after these 5 minuts).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JButton.setEnabled(false);
  //...
}
```

I don't want user to see that. I would like all these action execute in the background. What can I do to achive it?

Answer (score 8):

You should do such intensive tasks in another thread, not the dispatcher thread.

Some useful reading: [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, there are several Threads defined and suppose to start in actionPerformed(). So, putting all this into another Thread is not a very optimal idea, is it?

Comment: The first thing you do while processing is to disable the button, the last - enable it. It should disallow user clicking the button while processing.

Comment: @Sorrow: That's right. And that's why I put in the beginning "JButton.setEnabled(false);". After executing all actions button is enabling again.

Comment: @Jerry: Right, my mistake, I missed that. However, still, putting it to the worker should be the solution, despite creating new threads. You may eventually need some synchronisation at the end.

Comment: @Jerry, 5 people have upvoted this answer.  That should help you feel better about it.

Comment: @jzd Right, but I doubt that everyone who voted up, did it before I added my comment.

Comment: Which comment?  I voted after your last one, not sure when others voted, but using a SwingWorker to do this is absolutely correct.

Comment: @jzd Even if I have to put some other Threads into that Thread?

Comment: @Jerry, not sure what you are calling a Thread, but if it is blocking the EDT then it is not on another Thread.

Comment: @jzd I meant sth like Runnable a = new Runnable() {}

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the GUI-Thread is busy and will not repaint the component until processing has finsihed

You could do the activities in a backgroud thread.

Comment: Your first suggestion was correct, the background thread, but your second suggestion about calling update in Swing and getGraphics is incorrect and misleading. I suggest you delete it.

Comment: thank you, and I removed my down vote and changed it to an up-vote.